# How to associate ipynb files with Jupyter Lab (from Anaconda) on Windows 10

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I use Windows 10. Jupiter Lab is installed from Anaconda.

I want to associate `ipynb` files with Jupyter Lab so that, when I double click on `ipynb` file it should be opened using Jupyter Lab. How can I do it?

Comment: What currently happens if you double click them?

Comment: @AMC Windows opens standard dialog to choose program to open `ipynb` file. That means that `ipynb` is not associated with any program yet. Jupyter notebook and Jupiter lab are both installed on the PC and are working as intended.

Comment: I haven’t used Windows in a while, but I think you can right click -> open as, or tweak the file type-program associations from the file properties or the settings.

Comment: @AMC There is no Jupyter Lab from programs to choose from. Also I do not know to which `exe` file should I manually browse to (`exe` file for Jupiter Lab).

Comment: Manually browse to for what? That’s strange, that Jupyter Lab doesn’t show. When did you install it?

Comment: When you double click file that is not associated with any program dialog appears with list of programs to choose from. If the program that you need is not in that list you can browse for application `exe` file to which you want to associate your program with. I installed latest version of `Anaconda 3` 2-3 weeks ago and updated `conda` and `Anaconda 3` 2-3 days ago. Jupiter Lab, Jupyter Notebook and Python were automatically installed.

Comment: Can you open Jupyter Lab from Anaconda Navigator?

Comment: @AMC Yes, and it works fine.

Comment: That’s so strange...

Answer (score -1):

Install `nbopen`
this is the documentation https://github.com/takluyver/nbopen

```
pip install nbopen
python -m nbopen.install_win
```

if it does not work change

```
python -m nbopen.install_win
```

for

```
ipython -m nbopen.install_win
```

after that would you can to open your `*.ipynb` files with double click:
[image]

**Mark as answer if it solve your problem*

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.  Your screen shots and procedure are for Jupyter Classic Notebook.  The question was to launch "Jupyter Lab (from Anaconda) on Windows 10"  Please fix your answer.